# Upload empty folder to s3 using sdk

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to **upload** empty folder to s3 using SDK (Preffer .NET)?
As far as I know, I can't do it using AWS Console.

Has anybody Idea how I can do workaround using SDK to make it possible upload an empty folder? Because I need to create an application to make user possible to upload entire folder including empty folder.

Many thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, AWS suggests simulating empty folder by creating 0 byte file and deleting it once the first object in a folder being created.
You can find more details here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=50849